# Branch.io - Release Version doesn't work. Needs to be downloaded from GooglePlay?

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I have followed up the [sample app](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-Example-Deep-Linking-Branchster-Android) and the [documentation](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/quickstart_guide/android/#configuring-your-android-app) to setup my app to support deeplinking. 
I get my `link` like this: (also used the link from Branch Dashbord on the website)

```
> Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getContentUrl("viewer", null, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "URL is: " + url);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

When in test mode I use this in my `AndroidManifest` :

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true"/>
```

When I run the app from AndroidStudio and access the generated url from browser it always open my app, so it behaves as expected.

My problem is with the release version. When I click the `url` generated by the release version (signed apk) it doesn't work (prompt me to Google Play page instead).

Steps:

1. I remove the above line from `AndroidManifest` (also tried to set `<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />` still no use);
2. `Build-Generate Signed APK` then send the apk via email
3. Open the email on the device and click the link.

The link generated by the signed app **doesn't work**.

The link generated by the debug app **works as well** with the production app.

I don't know if is necessary to share any more code since the app works in test mode, but if needed, jsut tell me and I will do.

- What's wrong?
- Am I doing the right steps? Should the app be published on
     `GooglePlay` that the production link to work? (in my assumption
     not). Is this the correct approach?
- What link should I use when the app will be published to GooglePlay?
- Will any of the links work after I publish the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works after published to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

A few things jump out at me: 
1) You need to update your Branch key from the test version to the live version when you go from test to live.
2) Your description of why you think it's broken:

> My problem is with the release version. When I click the url generated by
>   the release version (signed apk) it doesn't work (prompt me to Google
>   Play page instead).

Remember that a Branch link is not a simple URI scheme invocation, clicking the link sends you to a server which checks if you've ever opened the app before based on data collected from the SDK.  If so, Branch invokes the URI scheme and launches the app.  If not, Branch directs you to the Google Play store.  So being directed to the Play store may be your expected behavior here, depending on if you're opening the app or not as part of your test flow (unclear from your description).

There's a doc that covers this flow here: https://dev.branch.io/how_branch_links_work/

My inclination is to think everything is working fine.  But if you're still uncertain please send us an email - support[at]branch.io - and we'll be more than happy to work through it with you.